# How can I hide a column of a <table> if a condition is met?

Tags: html, html-table, blazor

I have a `<table>` with several rows and columns. I want to hide the last column, if a specific variable `foo` in the code behind is -1.
Therefore, I cannot use CSS and the `:last-child` because in CSS, I do not have access to `foo`.
I tried to style the last column of a `<colgroup>` with `<col style="@(foo == -1d ? "visibility: collapse" : "")">` but that did not collapse the entire column but still showed super- and subscripts `<sup>`  and `sub`.
Of course, I could replace

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

with

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    @if (foo != -1)
    {
        <td></td>
    }
</tr>
```

at every row but I hope, there is a cleaner way.

Comment: It could be better factored if you were composing the table rows dynamically from a data source. But since, as the problem is stated, it seems the table is statically defined as html in your template, you are forced to put such a condition on each spot where you have a static html fragment that you wished to exclude

Comment: You can do this the CSS way, the razor way or both. As said before, you are gonna have to put the logic on every spot. However,  you can also replace it by a Blazor component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@if (foo...)` check to optionally define a CSS class. Make sure to use a class name that is unique given other CSS that may exist.

```
@if (foo == -1)
{
  <style type="text/css">
    .sometimesHidden { display: none; }
  </style>
}
...
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td class="sometimesHidden">X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td class="sometimesHidden">Y</td>
</tr>
```

Note that this will always render the last `<td>` of every `<tr>`. You'll need to make sure that those cells (and specifically their content) do not cause errors when rendered.

Or you can use an inline style:

```
@{
  var tdStyle = foo == -1 ? "display: none;" : "";
}
...
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td style="@(tdStyle)">X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td style="@(tdStyle)">Y</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I defined a bool in the background and did the case distinction in the `<td style>`. Defining a string directly, like you do, is even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Blazor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-content-render-fragments) for this:

MyLastColumn.razor

```cs
@if(Foo != -1){
  <td>@ChildContent</td>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it:

```
<MyLastColumn Foo="@foo">content</MyLastColumn>
```

Comment: That would work, but is a little too much in this simple case. Thanks anyway.